# React router auth pattern

Tags: reactjs, authentication, design-patterns

I am trying to implement the authentication using React + Firebase. I want to achieve a simple result. When user is not logged in, he sees "Welcome" on the Welcome component by "/" path. When user is logged in, he sees "Welcome, `username`". I implemented Login as a controlled component which has some fields(name, email) and signIn method. Same with Signup component. I cannot figure out how to better implement Welcome component which can receive props. I tried to pass in the props to Welcome component, but then it has  form and this cannot be passed into component prop of Route, thus i have an error. I also saw the solution with protected paths, but i don't need exactly protected paths from not authenticated users. I just want to pass user data from Login(firebase.auth().currentUser) to Welcome component. Could you please suggest better, modern or elegant way to implement such flow?

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter, Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import Welcome from './Welcome';
import Login from './Login';
import Signup from './Signup';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Welcome} />
          <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
          <Route path="/register" component={Signup} />
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are updating your state with the user's data after login success, you can just have your welcome component conditionally render two different messages based on the existence of the data in your state.

(pseudo code)

```
if: no user data
return (<p>Welcome</p>);

if: user data exists
return (<p>Welcome John Smith</p>);
```

Comment: Yeah, but how should I pass in user data into Welcome component?

Comment: This is where I would recommend learning redux. It will help you manage all of your data in a centralized store, and allow you to display it easily in components. https://www.valentinog.com/blog/react-redux-tutorial-beginners/

It will make everything you do in the future easier. Otherwise, in normal react, you can just pass an object containing the data as props through to the child welcome component. 
https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html

Comment: I just found a solution, but it seems not as best practice. I can wrap my Welcome component into a function which returns some html element containing Welcome component. Pass in some needed props. And then pass it func to component prop of Route.

Answer (score 0):

I've taken to using the React Context API to manage the auth state. The best tutorial I've seen on this is at https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-protect-your-routes-with-react-context-717670c4713a .  While there are simpler solutions, this one is pretty scalable and supports a lot of flexibility.

Comment: Two change/from the tutorial, it sets the value in the context in the render function of the provider (i.e. `<AuthContext.Provider value={{ isAuth: this.state.isAuth, login: this.login, logout: this.logout }} >`).  That's less than ideal as it always creates a new object which will cause any change to re-render all sub components.  It's much better to pass the object from state.

Comment: Also, create a HOC for passing in auth vs. adding context everywhere. So, in AuthContext.js, add something like this 
```export function withAuth(Component) {
  return function AuthedComponent(props) {
    return (
      <AuthContext.Consumer>
        {auth => <Component {...props} auth={auth} />}
      </AuthContext.Consumer>
    );
  };
}```